# Visual Studio Team Services Build - Publish to local NuGet feed

Tags: nuget, build-process, azure-devops

I'm trying to migrate from running Team Foundation Server locally to Visual Studio Team Services. I need to set up a build that will publish a nuget package to our local feed. Is this possible? I assume I need to set up VPN or something. I'm not even sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you planning to use an [on-premises build server](http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/) that should be easy enough? If not, you will have to create some sort of link from Azure into your network - I'm not sure of any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to local resources you either need to make it available online or use a local build server.

You can create private AAD integrated nugget servers with MyGet.